# How to call a method with conditional binding only if other property exists

Tags: swift, binding, conditional-statements

So i was wondering if its possible to call a method that uses other property in a conditional binding if other property is not nil in a one liner.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
if let foo = method(prop), bar = prop {
   // do something with foo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will invoke method(prop) only if prop in not nil:

```
if let prop = prop, let foo = method(prop) {
    // do something with foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use map:

```
if let foo = prop.map({ method($0) }) {
     // ...
}
```